# Print iterations when loop is inside a function R

Tags: r, for-loop, forecasting

I am trying to get a loop inside a function.

So the main idea is that you get a var model, periods for forecasting, the training set, and the real data (for the forecasted period).

So I am making up this function, that reorganizes the data and computes the MSFE, the loop works fine! But as soon as it is inside a function, it won't print the results in the console.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107117/compute-error-with-two-datasets-using-for-loop/71107134?noredirect=1#comment125696843_71107134) I asked about the loop, so I know it is working fine.

Since the desired output is text, I don't want to store the sentences. Just print them in the console, I don't know how to make it.

Thanks in advance!

---

This is the function:

```
MSFE <- function(var, periods, train, test){
  
  # Now for each variable compute the MSFE
  ## Recall that MSFE is mean((real-predicted)^2)
  
  # var is the model,
  # periods is the forecasted period
  # train is the training data (1971m1-2003m12)
  # test is the real data (2004m1-2004m12)
  fcast_data <- forecast(var, h=periods)
  test <- head(test, periods)
  
  fcast_data <- fcast_data %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% select(Time, Series, `Point Forecast`) %>% 
    spread(key="Series", value = `Point Forecast`) %>% 
    mutate(Time=toupper(Time),
           Time=gsub(" ","",Time),
           Time=paste0("01",Time),
           Time=dmy(Time)) %>% arrange(Time) %>% select(-Time)
    

    for(i in names(train)){
    msfe <- paste("The Mean Squared Forecast Error for",i,"is:",mean((test[,i]-fcast_data[,i])^2))
    print(msfe)
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create another function for printing the values and call it from inside the `MSFE` function?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what are you proposing.

Comment: Maybe you need to flush to console, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717453/680068

Comment: @zx8754 tried that but doesn't make any changes. Still not printing.

Comment: How are you calling this function?  IF you are calling it in parallel it would not be printing anything to your console but to the parallel session. One option for this not printing would be that `is.null(names(train))` returns true.

Comment: @Oliver i am calling it like this `MSFE(cee5_var,12,cee5, cee5_comp)`

Comment: One option for this not printing would be that `is.null(names(train))` returns true

Comment: oh damn it does return true

Comment: try `colnames(train)` perhaps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241998/discussion-between-jorge-paredes-and-oliver).